# How to correctly add external library license into Android Project

Tags: android, github

I have developed an android project and I am planning to publish it in this week. However, I have problem. In this project I am using external libraries in github like picasso, okhttp and emojicons. How can I add the license of these libraries into my project to avoid any copyright problems. Thank you,

Comment: so do you finally have the answer to this.